# Flex: make child with same height of absolute sibling

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I must create a section with two half divs with the same height, but the first must inside the container and other outside, like that sketch:
[image]

I have searched other solutions but I couldn't get them to work, like flex:1, align-stretch, probably because of the way I did it. Maybe you can fresh my mind, by suggesting another way.

Here is my code:

```css
.bg-cyan {
  background-color: cyan;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.right-half {
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.col-6 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">


<section class="position-relative bg-cyan">
  <div class="container position-static p-0">
    <div class="row align-items-stretch">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h4 class="text-secondary mb-6">This col must be the same height of sibling absolute -></h4>
        <h3>Staying inside the container</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame;</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame;</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame;</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame;</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame;</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 position-absolute right-half p-0">
        This is absolute positioned because the layout require the image to go outside of container until the page end, with no height setted because of responsive and dynamism.
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/956/870">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to make the right side to absolute, just use the flexbox feature itself. Try this:

```css
.bg-cyan {
  background-color: cyan;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.right-half {
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.container {
  display: 'flex';
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex-direction: 'row';
}

.col-6 {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: 'auto';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">


<section class="position-relative bg-cyan">
  <div class="container position-static p-0">
    <div class="row align-items-stretch">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h4 class="text-secondary mb-6">This col must be the same height of sibling absolute -></h4>
        <h3>Staying inside the container</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame;</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame;</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame;</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame;</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame;</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 p-0">
        This is absolute positioned because the layout require the image to go outside of container until the page end, with no height setted because of responsive and dynamism.
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/956/870">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I cant see the solution. The absolute position of right col is because the image needs to touch the right end of screen, while fill 50% of remaining space on container. I updated my question with an sketch of it.